# Add new line in typescript (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to have a new line displayed in a string in my template. For some reason the new line is ignored. `<br/>` is not working, neither does `\n`.

Here is my function:

```
this.errorsString = '';
this.validateData();
for ( var i = 0; i < this.errors.length; i++){
    this.errorsString += `${this.errors[i]}` +'<br/>'
    console.log(this.errors[i])
}
```

html:

```
<div *ngIf="errorsString" >
    <div class="redError">
        {{ errorsString }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are using this error string with innerHTML in template?

Comment: or use \n and css style white-space

Comment: <div *ngIf="errorsString" >
    <div class="redError">
      {{ errorsString }}
    </div>
  </div>

Comment: try this `this.errorsString +=\`${this.error[i]}\n\` ` or `this.errorsString += this.errors+''+'\n' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use ngFor on a "p" element. If you have a list of errors you can just iterate over them in the component template using ngFor on a Paragraph and have your line break accodingly.

app.component.ts

```
// An array that contains all errors which can also be filled up later, just an example
public errors = ['error1', 'error2', 'error3'];
```

app.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="errors.length != 0">
    <div class="red-error">
        <p *ngFor="let error of errors">{{ error }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using innerHTML to write the html on the html document:

```
<div *ngIf="errorsString">
  <div class="redError" innerHTML="{{ errorsString }}">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how about in ur ts change to this: 
this.errorsString += `${this.errors[i]} <br>`

Answer (score 0):

Just join the items using '<br />' and use innerHtml

```typescript
  public errors = ["error1", "error2", "error3"];
  errorsString = this.errors.length > 0 ? this.errors.join("<br />") : null;
```

In your html

```html
<div *ngIf="errorsString">
  <div class="redError" innerHTML="{{ errorsString }}">
  </div>
</div>
```

[See Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-25oki9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)